# How to use query parameters, as "_fields", to filter data inside an array in the REST API?

Tags: rest-api

How to handle this endpoint

> `/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?_fields=name,meta_data`

```
[
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "meta_data": [
            {
                "id": 478626,
                "key": "_wp_page_template",
                "value": "default"
            },
```

to achieve this?

```
[
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "meta_data": [
            {
                "value": "default"
            },
```

I took a look at the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/#_fields), but I didn't find anything relevant.

Since `meta_data` is an `array`, this syntax DOESN'T work:

> `/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?_fields=name,meta_data.value`

Comment: The linked [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/#_fields) says, "*As of WordPress 5.3 the `_fields` parameter supports **nested** properties*", so try `_fields=name,meta_data.value`..? But can't you just retrieve only the `value` property from within your application?

Comment: It DOESN'T WORK, Sally, because "meta_data" is an array.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I didn't notice the `[`. And I don't think an "any (numeric) array key" is supported (i.e. the key must be explicitly specified, e.g. `meta_data.0.value` and `meta_data.1.value`), so maybe you should just use the standard way - keep the original structure and in your app, get just the property you need from each item in the `meta_data` array.

Comment: `meta_data.0.value` DOESN'T work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does this only work with the meta_data object for accessing nested items in an array? I tried it with woo commerce subscription line_items and did not seem to work.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/258308)